# How are σ+ values in Hammett Plots calculated?

Tags: equilibrium, aromatic-compounds, nucleophilic-substitution

First of all, I know a similar question has already been asked & answered about σ values in general, however, I am not 100 % sure this answer is correct for the following situation.

So for the σ values, we know we have the following formula:

$$\log \left(\frac{K_x}{K_h} \right)=\sigma_x$$

with the equilibrium values being determined for the deprotonation of benzoic acid for different substituents. So, most logically we would find electron-withdrawing groups (EWG) having positive $\sigma_x$ values and electron-donating groups (EDG) having negative $\sigma_x$ values.

However, for the Hammett plot corrected for the stabilization of positive charge through resonance ($\sigma^+$) with the reference reaction being another reaction (see figure below), we still see the same trend for $\sigma_x$ values whereas we would expect the exact opposite.

[[image: <span class=]$S_N1$ heterolysis reaction of para-substituted phenyl dimethyl chloromethane">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ap0Bh.png)

According to the literature, this inverse trend for EWG and EDG is being done purposely by changing the formula but I cannot find the formula. Does anyone know how this is done? Thank you in advance!